# Cannot read List<myClass> from a webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, serialization, asmx

I have a webservice that returns a list.

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "GetBatchList", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
public List<Batch> GetBatchList()
{        
List<Batch> listBatches = null;

    try
    {
        listBatches = api.GetBatchList();
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }

    return listBatches;
}
```

where

```
public class Batch
{
    public string BatchName { get; set; }
    public List<MAASUsers> Users { get; set; }
}

public class MAASUsers
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string sourceEmail { get; set; }
    public int sourceTenantID { get; set; }
    public string targetEmail { get; set; }
    public int targetTenantID { get; set; }
    public string migrationStatus { get; set; }
}
```

In the client side of the application, I cannot manage to get the content correctly.
How can I consume the webservice respons.

I've attempted in vain this solution: [datacontractserializer deserialize list<> always empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062635/datacontractserializer-deserialize-list-always-empty)
I've also tried another solution below.
But, for both solutions I'm stuck retrieving the list : List Users

```
// Call the webservice, then read the respons
[...]
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    DataSet dsTable = new DataSet();
    dsTable.ReadXml(response.GetResponseStream(), XmlReadMode.Auto);
    if (dsTable.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        table = dsTable.Tables[0];
    }
}

if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    list = (from DataRow row in table.Rows
      select new Batch
      {
           BatchName = row["BatchName"].ToString()
           /////// But here how do I get List<MAASUsers> Users? 
           /////// the content is returned in dsTable.Tables[1]
           /////// and I don't see any "joining key" ???
      }).ToList();
}
```

Note that the webservice has correctly sent the content of List ( see [datacontractserializer deserialize list<> always empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062635/datacontractserializer-deserialize-list-always-empty) for sample XML returned)

Comment: What type of web service is this?  WCF?  Using the REST project template?

Comment: this is a standard visual studio 2010 webservice project, developped by an external company. The webservice (server side) is workinf fine and returning correct xml data. This issue should be resolved on client side in an elegant way (of course I could parse the XML with a dom or sax parser) but I expect a more standard solution (builtin deserialization or whatever)

Comment: Just FYI that there is not a closing double-quote here: BatchName = row["BatchName ].ToString()

Comment: no problem, I have edited the code to hide and replace the real names. The app compiles correctly.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

There is a relation table. The dataset adds them automatically and add a "Class"_ID to each row that facilitates the relation between the tables.
See below how to use it.

```
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    DataSet dsTable = new DataSet();
    dsTable.ReadXml(response.GetResponseStream(), XmlReadMode.Auto); 
    lstMaasBatches= (from DataRow row in dsTable.Tables[0].Rows
                select new MAASBatch
                {
                    BatchName = row["BatchName"].ToString(),
                    BatchId = Convert.ToInt32(row["MAASBatch_Id"].ToString())                        
                }).ToList();

    foreach (MAASBatch batch in lstMaasBatches)
    {
        int batchID = batch.BatchId;
        List<MAASUsers> lst = (from DataRow row in dsTable.Tables[2].Rows
                                           where row.Field<int>("Users_Id") == batchID 
                     select new MAASUsers
                     {
                         ID = Convert.ToInt32(row["ID"].ToString()),
                         firstName = Convert.ToString(row["FirstName"].ToString()),
                         lastName = Convert.ToString(row["LastName"].ToString()),
                         migrationStatus = row["migrationStatus"].ToString(),
                         sourceEmail = Convert.ToString(row["SourceEmail"].ToString()),
                         sourceAgentID = Convert.ToInt32(row["sourceTenantID"].ToString()),
                         targetEmail = Convert.ToString(row["TargetEmail"].ToString()),
                         targetAgentID = Convert.ToInt32(row["targetTenantID"].ToString()),
                     }).ToList();
                    batch.Users = lst;
                }                   
     }
}
```